# Box -> View API -> Can not authenticate to create session

Tags: box-view-api

in this site :https://developers.box.com/view/
I do follow the instruction in the example (use Postman or curl)

curl https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions \
-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"document_id": "ABC123"}' \
-X POST

YOUR_API_KEY is replaced by my api key
ABC123 is replaced by a my pdf file.

But I got result: {"message": "Unsupported media type 'application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in request.", "type": "error", "request_id": "1f3d91c9489247579c78e7ceaa5e67c8"}

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the spaces after your `\` characters. If you try:

```
curl https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions \
-H "Authorization: Token APIKEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"document_id": "DOCID"}' \
-X POST
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank seanrose, I have made some change in my code and been able to avoid that error, but I face another problem ,I post here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283761/box-view-api-can-not-create-session-for-an-document-id